# How to delete and reload resource and behaviour packs in bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

I loaded a resource pack and it is corrupted. I need to delete it and reload it. But I don't know to delete it. If I try to overwrite, it says duplicate name detected. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To uninstall resource packs in the Minecraft Bedrock, you have to use the **Global Storage option**. It cannot be done from the Resource Packs option on the world settings page. Follow the steps below and you will be done in no time.

1. Open the Minecraft App.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Select the Storage option.
4. Click on the Resources Packs tab.
5. Find and click on the resource pack you want to remove.
6. Click on the Delete icon.
7. Click on the Delete button.
8. Repeat for the Behavior Pack.

The above steps are further explained below-

---

**1. Open the Minecraft App**

You can do this by searching for it in the Start menu or by clicking on the Minecraft tile appearing on the right side of the Start menu.

**2. Click on settings**

Click the Settings button on the main screen. This will take you to the main Minecraft settings page where you can configure the global settings.

**3. Select the storage option**

Select the Storage option on the left sidebar. This is the option that shows all your worlds and resource packs installed in the Minecraft bedrock edition.

**4. Click on the resource packs tab**

Click on the Resources Packs tab on the right panel. This action expands the respective tab to show all the installed resource packs.

**5. Find and click on the resource pack you want to remove.**

Find and click on the resource pack you want to remove. This should show more options related to that resource pack.

**6. Click on the delete icon**

Tap the Delete icon from the extended menu.

**7. Click on the delete button**

Click on the Delete button in the confirmation window. Doing this will confirm your action to delete the resource pack.

As soon as you click the Delete button, Minecraft will remove that resource pack almost instantly. If you have multiple resource packs to uninstall then click on the Multiselect option at the top, select all the resource packs you want to remove and click the Delete button to remove them.

**8. Repeat for Behavior Packs**

The process should be the same except for the obvious change in titles from "resource" to "behavior".

---

*I hope this helps. If you still need some help, comment below and I will try to help as much as possible.*

Comment: Thanks it helped me so much